# return a multidimensional json array using json.net

Tags: c#, json.net

I have this code:

```
var all_books = db.Books;
var result = all_books.Select(a => new { a.bookid, a.booktitle, a.bookisbn}).Take(4).ToList();

var jsonData = new {
                sEcho = param.sEcho,
                iTotalRecords = all_assets.Count(),
                iTotalDisplayRecords = all_assets.Count(),
                aaData = result
            };
return Json(jsonData,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

And the json returned is in the form of:

```
{"sEcho":null,"iTotalRecords":2764,"iTotalDisplayRecords":2764,"aaData":[{"bookid":"M-711745","booktitle":"20844","bookisbn":"HP LA2205wg"},{"bookid":null,"booktitle":"n/a","bookisbn":"n/a"},{"bookid":"M-710587","booktitle":"20707","bookisbn":"HP LA2205wg"},{"bookid":"735129","booktitle":"21272","bookisbn":"HP LA2205wg"}]}
```

I would like to return a multidimensional array instead.

```
{"sEcho":null,"iTotalRecords":2764,"iTotalDisplayRecords":2764,"aaData":[["bookid":"M-711745","booktitle":"20844","bookisbn":"HP LA2205wg"],["bookid":null,"booktitle":"n/a","bookisbn":"n/a"],["bookid":"M-710587","booktitle":"20707","bookisbn":"HP LA2205wg"],["bookid":"735129","booktitle":"21272","bookisbn":"HP LA2205wg"]]}
```

I have tried this code:

```
var result = all_books.Select(a => new List<string[]>() { new string[]{ a.bookid, a.booktitle, a.bookisbn }}).Take(4);
```

But I get this error:

```
The array type 'System.String[]' cannot be initialized in a query result. Consider using 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]' instead.
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var result = all_books
    .Select(a => new List<string> { a.bookid, a.booktitle, a.bookisbn })
    .Take(4)
    .ToList();
```

When you serialize it, you should get the following JSON, which I think is what you are shooting for:

```
{
    "sEcho":null,
    "iTotalRecords":2764,
    "iTotalDisplayRecords":2764,
    "aaData":
    [
        ["M-711745","20844","HP LA2205wg"],
        [null,"n/a","n/a"],
        ["M-710587","HP LA2205wg","20707"],
        ["735129","HP LA2205wg","21272"]
    ]
}
```